# Tomcat 7: cached copy of war file deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, war

I am trying to deploy a war file on tomcat . Each time I make a modification I generate a war and deploy it to tomcat (Using the tomcat manager) to check my changes . Suddenly each time I deploy a changed war , tomcat seems to be hosting an old version of the file ( Which I suspect is a cached copy) . I tried re-installing tomcat , restarting my computer etc . I also extracted the files from the war to check if the changes exist and they do . Any help on how I could debug or work on this problem will be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try cleaning up the following folders / files:

$TOMCAT_HOME\webapps\yourapplication

$TOMCAT_HOME\webapps\yourapplication.war

$TOMCAT_HOME\work\Catalina\localhost\yourapplication

$TOMCAT_HOME\temp

Comment: So in addition , I had cleared the war from the webapps folder but I did not find a copy of my war in the work folder

Comment: @user1801279 - You won't find the WAR file in the work directory, but you may find files that were generated from files in the WAR file; e.g. Java classes generated from your JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

By default, tomcat uses a subdirectory called `work` to hold a cached copy of the exploded war. If you are having issues with old files hanging around, that is probably where they are. You might also check your tomcat log file for messages that are generated when you deploy the new version of the war regarding files that could not be removed during the undeploy phase.

Comment: So in addition , I had cleared the war from the webapps folder but I did not find a copy of my war in the work folder